# Add Simple Diagonal Line to Google Scatter Chart

Tags: google-visualization, scatter-plot

I'm looking for a way to add a diagonal line, not a trend line, that would be independent from the actual data. I want it to start at the bottom left and end a the top right. Is there a good way to do this using Google Charts?

http://i572.photobucket.com/albums/ss169/danielsussman/ScreenShot2014-12-03at23337AM_zpsabbac43a.png